# Resize div element for different media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to resize the div element that contains a slideshow for the different media queries but I cannot find a proper solution.

The .html is listed below

```
        <div class="content" id="cont">
            <div id="sbi_container" class="sbi_container">

                <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="resources/img/backgroundcust.jpeg">
                    <a href="#" class="sbi_label" onclick="hideit()">x</a>
                </div>
                <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/4.jpg">
                    <a href="#" class="sbi_label" onclick="hideit2()">x</a>
                </div>
                <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/5.jpg">
                    <a href="#" class="sbi_label" onclick="hideit3()">xy</a>

                </div>
                <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/6.jpg">
                    <a href="#" class="sbi_label" onclick="hideit4()">xxy</a>
                </div>

                <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/6.jpg">
                    <a href="#" class="sbi_label" onclick="hideit5()">yy</a>
                </div>
                <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/6.jpg">
                    <a href="#" class="sbi_label" onclick="hideit6()">yy</a>
                </div>
                <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/6.jpg">
                    <a href="#" class="sbi_label" onclick="hideit7()">xxy</a>
                </div>
                <div class="sbi_panel" data-bg="images/6.jpg">
                    <a href="#" class="sbi_label" onclick="hideit8()">Foam</a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The .css for the media query is listed below:

```
media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.sbi_container{
     max-width:400px;
    display: block;
}}
```

The problem is that this solution just resize the whole slideshow and it doesn't show all the slides.

Can you please suggest a solution?

Comment: You forgot @ in @media only screen and...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can re-compose the code in your `onclick` handlers into a single function. This way you don't have to maintain 8+ `hideitX` functions. I would also suggest not using inline JavaScript and delegate the click events to `.sbi_container`.

Comment: @Roy I didn't forgot it...I just didn't paste it here...My mistake!